# Assign prefix sum of a vector and store result in a static vector

Tags: c++, static

Let's assume there is a function definition like:

```
int PrefixSum(vector<int>& nums, int pos) {
    static vector<int> prefixsum = ....
    return nums[pos];
}
```

I want to precalculate prefixsum vector since the function will be called multiple times.
It is assumed that nums vector does not change, so a static prefixsum vector is valid.
Also, I cant change the function definition due to legacy purposes.

Comment: so what is the problem / question?

Comment: @Rajs123 What is the prefix sum?

Comment: I wouldnt use a `static` here. What if later you pass a different `nums`? Then the prefixsum will be wrong. On the other hand if `nums` is always the same, why pass it on each call? Why not wrap it in a class that has prefixsum as member and a method that does only `return nums[pos];` ? When you say you cannot change the definition, do you mean you cannot change the signature?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The cumulative partial sums. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum

Comment: @Rajs123 what seems to be the issue ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward approach can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

long long int PrefixSum( const std::vector<int>& nums, 
                         std::vector<long long int>::size_type pos ) 
{
    static std::vector<long long int> prefixsum;

    if ( prefixsum.empty() )
    {
        prefixsum.reserve( nums.size() );
        std::partial_sum( std::begin( nums ), std::end( nums ), 
                          std::back_inserter( prefixsum ) );
    }

    return prefixsum[pos];
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    std::cout << PrefixSum( v, v.size() - 1 ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
45
```

Answer (score 0):

### Init with lambda function

Using a lambda function to initialize the static variable could like this:

```
static std::vector<long long int> prefixsum = []{
        std::vector<long long int> temp( nums.size() );
        std::partial_sum( std::begin( nums ), std::end( nums ), 
                          std::begin( temp) );
        return temp;
}();
```